# How to force a TableRow to wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to build a really simple TableLayout, with 2 columns and an undeterminate number of rows.
In the first columns, I put a TextView, which MUST BE written on 2 lines :

```
    <string name="param_period_data_rec_text">Période d\'acquisition des données\n(secondes)</string>
```

And in the second column, I put an EditText.

My problem is : the EditText's height is about 1 and a half lines of text, and the TableRows wraps around it, hiding the half of the second line of the TextView.

Of course, I would like the TextView to be displayed completely. How should I do?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@color/blanc"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/param_frequence_data_rec_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/param_period_data_rec_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/param_frequence_data_rec_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/param_period_data_rec_input"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/param_frequence_data_rec_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/param_period_data_rec_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/param_frequence_data_rec_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="editText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</TableRow>
```

update: textVeiw and editText width = 0dp, so that layout_weight="1" property can work

Comment: Your solution works. It's not exactly what I asked, but actually, I think it's better, because it adapts the number of columns in function of the lenght of the String

Comment: No need to specify layout_width or layout_height for a TableRow (it just makes your code snippet more confusing), according to this:

"The children of a TableLayout cannot specify the layout_width attribute. Width is always MATCH_PARENT. However, the layout_height attribute can be defined by a child; default value is WRAP_CONTENT. If the child is a TableRow, then the height is always WRAP_CONTENT."
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `fill_parent` in your `TextView`.

Comment: It seems to work, but it still works when I remove it... Maybe I just needed to clean my project

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
android:minLines="2"
```

to the tag describing the widget that needs to have at least two lines.  wrap_content (which you already have) should take care of the rest.

Comment: It seems to work, but it still works when I remove it... Maybe I just needed to clean my project